# Highstocks line chart issue after HS upgrade

Tags: highcharts

We are current upgrading a four yr old HS application to the newest version.

The following screenshot show a red dashed line going from 1302 down to 0 on the last day.

http://de.tinypic.com/r/10s96a8/8

The same is displayed with the newsted HS version this way:

http://de.tinypic.com/r/10s96a8/8

I tried to play with plotOptions -> line -> step: center|right|left but this does lead to a step within in the line..
so any recommendation how to restore the old correct behavior?

Comment: There is also a screencast here: [link](http://public.zopyx.com/hs.mp4) - it shows that the red line turns into an upright line as soon as you zoom into the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related with datagrouping, which group points. So when you zoom, points are calculated and merge into single, to increase performance. Try to disable that by option. Ref: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.enabled